# How can we hide ActionBar Tabs in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm developing an app in which I've used `Tabs` with `Swipes` enabled, and I just wanted to know that can I hide the `ActionBar` `Tabs` in my layout? I want to hide Tab 0 title, tab 1 title, tab 2 title, etc...Is this possible? Any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks!

[image: I want to hide these tabs.]

Comment: you can add and remove instead of hiding

Comment: But I want to keep the functionality of the tabs, and just want to make them invisible, in fact I want to hide tabs...

Comment: when and where you need to show/hide tabs ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a launcher where there'll be three activities, which can be changed by swiping right or left...So if i hide tabs, then it would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tabs, you should be using a `ViewPager`. You can find google's example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: I viewed the Google documentation before, but I want to switch `ACTIVITIES` by swiping right or left, is it possible?

Comment: with viewpager not, is there any particular reason why you are switching activities instead of fragments?

Comment: I'm actually trying to make a launcher, that's why...Can I use particular XMLs as fragments?

Comment: you can define your own XML layout for a fragment, yes. also you can provide the swiping animations and stuff for viewpager. sliding tabs are obsolute if you ask me

Comment: I can make a simple example project. But I need to know one thing, you want no indication on where the user is?

Comment: I just want to make the user swipe between activities, and activities should be fullscreen, is it possible?